# MLCC capacitor uF

Tags: capacitor, mlcc

Looking for help with a repair please
to be able to advise a capacitor rating.

I have a 13.5V 5W 21 x led strip.
Each LED 70ma 2.2  forward voltage.
Apart from that 1pc SOD 2pcs 1k resisitor and 47r x 21

Hopefully someone with more knowledge than could fit on a postage stamp (me) can offer a helping hand to work out suitable uF for this head scratcher
Tried 16V 47uf and it shorted a LED at end of circuit.
I feel old cap is breaking down as leds behind it in middle of board have shorted out more than once and are getting a slightly higher fv reading
It's also pulling more current the longer it's illuminated [image][image]

Comment: How *exactly* do the capacitor(s) relate to the LEDs in terms of circuit connection?  What did the original part look.like?

Comment: Hi Chris I've tried to upload a pic

Comment: IS this for a vehicle?  What is the supply Vmax? You don't need a cap yet

Comment: It's not clear what you are wanting to understand or how someone can help.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the capacitor is required for or where you intend to put it.

Comment: Capacitor is on board already I can only think fault relates to that

Answer (score 0):

LED's have been fried from an overvoltage source, so current will rise as the LEDs get much hotter as the Vf of LEDs drops with rising temp.

The key evidence is the burning of the green epoxy FR4.

### example

If this is rated for 13.5V max and you are using 14.5V from a vehicle, you would need to add a voltage drop 1V power resistor  5W/13.5V = 370 mA  thus 1V/0.37 = 2.7 Ohms and Pd = 1W so use a 5W for 125'C/5 = 25'C rise

Comment: All leds replaced it was the boiling flux that caused the dark spotting to epoxy

Comment: How did that happen?  Where are the design details?

Comment: Supply v reads 11.6 part stares 13.5max 5w

Comment: Where are the design details?

Comment: I don't have design details I've added a couple of images to show components

Comment: Where did you find this board? what is it intended for ? what supply did you use?  Did you solder the parts? how many were replaced?  What colour?

Comment: It's an auto brake light insert 12v power I replaced all led chips and a couple of 1kohm resistors that had crusted on one side red 1.8 2.2v osram

Comment: The auto probably uses a Current limiter design which is easy